# Python ValueError for code that calculates correct results

Tags: python, valueerror

Problem Statement

Given an integer n, find two integers a and b such that,

```
#a >= 0 and b >= 0
#a + b = n
#DigitSum(a) + Digitsum(b) is maximum of all possibilities

def solve(n): 

    len_of_n = len(str(n))
    len_of_n-=1
    a = '9'
    a = (a*len_of_n)
    #print(a)
    b = (int(n) - int(a) )  # This is the line where it points to error.
    #print(b)

    digits_of_a = []
    digits_of_b = []
    for i in str(a)[::-1]:
         digits_of_a.append(int(i))   
    for i in str(b)[::-1]:
         digits_of_b.append(int(i))

    return (sum(digits_of_a) + sum(digits_of_b))
```

The code actually reports correct answers on test cases on 'attempts' on codewars.com but fails final submission. It exits with error code 1. It says ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I have read this other thread on this and understand that error is due to  trying to convert a space character to an integer. Can't figure why would that statement get space charater. Both of them are int representations of string...?

Comment: What are the values of `n` and `a` when it hits the error? It And what are you passing into the function? The most likely thing, I think, is that the string `n` is unable to be casted to an int, either because it's an empty string or because it has non-digit characters in it.

Comment: N is already an int why would you int(n) ?

Comment: Do you by any chance pas a single digit value?

Comment: **n** is an integar passed to the func. **a** is constructed on the fly based on total 'digits' in the n. Error suggests it's due to empty string. But I cannot figure why/how can I have empty string with valid int value **n** passed to the def.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert 

Had changed as part of trial and error.. 

Originally I just had **(n - int(a))**



I am not sure what values are passed by the test engine. The test cases on codewars shows all 8 assertions passed but then also shows this error. So it deems my code inadmissible. Snapshot below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a single digit int to the function you get this error because `len_of_n = len(str(n))` will be equal to 1 and 
`len_of_n-=1` will be equal to 0. `0 * '9'` will give you an empty string which can not be converted to an int. Thus giving you the error

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: Bingo! 

Makes sense. Let me edit and give one more go!

Comment: @JigishParikh you will probably need to make an extra case if n is only 1 digit.